# Async function as callback

Tags: javascript

I just started using async/await and is confused on how it interacts with callback. For example,

```
fooMethod(function() {
    return Promise.resolve("foo");
});
```

vs

```
fooMethod(async function() { //add async keyword
    return "foo";
});
```

Must fooMethod be written in a specific way so that it can handle an `async` function as callback?

if `fooMethod` is a public library, how do I know that it is safe to add `async` keyword to the function?

**FOLLOW UP**

Express router,

```
app.get('/foo', function (req, res) {
  return res.send("foo");
});



app.get('/foo', async function (req, res) {
  return res.send("foo");
});
```

both of these function works, is it safe to use though?

Comment: There is no point of using `async` when you don't `await`

Comment: @RoyiNamir this is just a simple example, I was just confuse on the interaction with callback of a possibly public library

Comment: `fooMethod` must be written in a specific way, it must handle promise returning function. If it doesn't, none of your examples work, if it does then both examples work.

Comment: @TamasHegedus That’s incorrect — if the function doesn’t do anything with the return value, then it doesn’t need to handle returned `Promises` differently.

Comment: @JF you mean if the function just ends with `cb()` then we are safe to add async keyword but if the functtion ends with `const result = cb()` then it will not support async keyword unless it resolve the promise from the callback?

Comment: Node supports async/await, so yes it is safe to use, but if you are not using the async function for async purposes there's no point to it

Comment: @realseanp thanks, yea inside that async function ill be doing `await` etc. My point is, looking at express documentation, I find no documenation about whether using async might casue problem to the callback.

Comment: @JF what about rejections? If the framework does not handle promises then rejections will be lost.

Comment: @TamasHegedus I’m pretty sure Node will warn about unhandled rejections, and IIRC it will throw in a futer version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two callbacks are equivalent. An `async function` is just syntactic sugar for a regular `function` that returns a `Promise`. This means that you can call an `async function` like a regular function. Here’s a demo:

```js
const foo = async function (arg) {
  return arg * 2
}
const bar = function (arg) {
  return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    return arg * 2
  })
}

const fooReturn = foo(2)
const barReturn = bar(2)
console.log('foo(2) =>', fooReturn.toString())
console.log('bar(2) =>', barReturn.toString())

fooReturn.then(fooResult => console.log('await foo(2) =>', fooResult))
barReturn.then(barResult => console.log('await bar(2) =>', barResult))
```

However, if the code that takes the callback wants to get a response, you won’t be able to use an async function unless the code is specially designed to check the return value of the callback function and `await` it if it’s a `Promise`.

Comment: Hi, so when can I know I can't use async keyword in a callback?

Comment: @Zanko I’ve edited my answer; does the edit clarify that issue?

Comment: i have edited my answer, do you mind clarifying the follow up? Thank you so much!

Comment: Yep, that should be safe @Zanko. Express controllers like those are meant to be asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks, I posted a comment too : ) Hope you can verify that!

Comment: There shouldn’t be a problem there. On another note, if you feel that this answer helped you, please upvote it using the up arrow and/or click the gray checkmark to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I am just trying to understand based on my own word. You mean if the function just ends with cb() then we are safe to add async keyword but if the functtion ends with const result = cb() then it will not support async keyword unless it resolve the promise from the callback?

Comment: Yes, that’s the gist of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your two functions are equivalent, but below demonstrates how using `await` in an `async function` delays the function execution by an extra tick each time:

```js
function syncTest() {
  console.log('sync completed')
  return Promise.resolve('foo')
}

async function asyncTest() {
  console.log('async completed')
  return 'foo'
}

async function awaitTest() {
  console.log('await started')
  await void 0
  console.log('await awaited')
  await void 0
  console.log('await completed')
  return 'foo'
}

console.log('start')

syncTest().then(value => console.log(`sync resolved: ${value}`))
asyncTest().then(value => console.log(`async resolved: ${value}`))
awaitTest().then(value => console.log(`await resolved: ${value}`))

Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => console.log('tick 2 completed'))
  .then(() => console.log('tick 3 completed'))
  .then(() => console.log('tick 4 completed'))

console.log('tick 1 completed')
```